πρόνοια meaning
Pausanias, Description of Greece 8.8.3:

τούτοις Ἑλλήνων ἐγὼ τοῖς λόγοις ἀρχόμενος μὲν τῆς συγγραφῆς εὐηθίας ἔνεμον πλέον, ἐς δὲ τὰ Ἀρκάδων προεληλυθὼς πρόνοιαν περὶ αὐτῶν τοιάνδε ἐλάμβανον: Ἑλλήνων τοὺς νομιζομένους σοφοὺς δι᾽ αἰνιγμάτων πάλαι καὶ οὐκ ἐκ τοῦ εὐθέος λέγειν τοὺς λόγους, καὶ τὰ εἰρημένα οὖν ἐς τὸν Κρόνον σοφίαν εἶναί τινα εἴκαζον Ἑλλήνων.

An English Translation:

When I started out, I used to see in these tales of the Greeks a higher degree of simple-mindedness in their authors, but on getting as far as Arcadia I started to hold this sort of view of them: In ancient times those among the Greeks who were considered wise spoke their sayings not straight out but in enigmas, and so the legends about Kronos I conjectured to be a certain sort of Greek wisdom.

Can πρόνοια mean "view"? According to this sentence, I can't find the appropriate meaning for πρόνοια in dictionaries.

For the Ancient Greek usage, the equivalents of πρόνοια are usually given as forethought, foreknowledge, and foresight.
In the mentioned context, it may be better to add the connotations "approaching with caution", "taking into consideration circumspectly". Indeed, the Loeb Classical Library translates the paragraph as

When I began to write my history I was inclined to count these legends
as foolishness, but on getting as far as Arcadia I grew to hold a
more thoughtful view of them, which is this. In the days of old
those Greeks who were considered wise spoke their sayings not straight
out but in riddles, and so the legends about Cronus I conjectured to
be one sort of Greek wisdom. In matters of divinity, therefore, I
shall adopt the received tradition.

